# Convergence of moments of weakly stationary process to stationary distribution

Tags: convergence-divergence, stationary-processes

browsing Internet while preparing for my exam I came across an interesting exercise.

Consider a weakly stationary process $Y_t$ and $I_t=Y_t, Y_{t-1},...$ information available at time $t$.

Show that $E(Y_{t+h}|I_t)$ and $V(Y_{t+h}|I_t)$ converge to the moments of the
stationary distributions, as the forecasting horizon $h$ increases.

Could you please help me show why this holds?

Comment: Since $E(Y_{t+h}\mid I_t)$ is a random variable, in which sense is the convergence supposed to hold?

Comment: That is what I dont understand.. there was no additional info about this